# How to check which the configuration maven uses for tests?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, unit-testing, maven

I have spring application. I see different behaviour when I use

**1** -

> run as -> jUnit test

on application

it is good works.

**2-**

> run as -> maven test

In surefire reports I see very long trace. The cause that :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/epam/hhsystem/util/DatabaseHelper;
```

How I can to know what configuration uses maven?

I develop in Spring Tool Suit

**UPDATE**

If I try

```
Project -> Clean
```

and after

`mvn clean test` from cmd
I see

```
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI>mvn clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hhsystem ui 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ ui ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ ui ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ ui ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] bad path element "": no such file or directory
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyContextListener.java:[8,29]
 cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyContextListener.jav
a:[12,1] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.MyContextListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyApplicationListener
.java:[10,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyApplicationListener
.java:[16,1] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.MyApplicationListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\ApplicationWebListene
r.java:[9,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\ApplicationWebListene
r.java:[14,1] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.ApplicationWebListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[12,23] package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[24,16] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Logger
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CustomAuthentificationProvider
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\AbstractController.ja
va:[49,20] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getAllSkills()
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.services.UtilService
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[24,32] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Logger
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CustomAuthentificationProvider
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[59,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[63,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[64,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[65,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[66,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\VacancyMenuController
.java:[79,20] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getAllSkills()
location: class com.epam.hhsystem.services.UtilService
[INFO] 16 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.059s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 23 18:52:14 MSK 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/162M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project ui:
 Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] bad path element "": no such file or directory
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyContextListener.jav
a:[8,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyContextListener.jav
a:[12,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.MyContextListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyApplicationListener
.java:[10,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\MyApplicationListener
.java:[16,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.MyApplicationListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\ApplicationWebListene
r.java:[9,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: package com.epam.hhsystem.util
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\ApplicationWebListene
r.java:[14,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class DatabaseHelper
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.ApplicationWebListener
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[12,23] package org.apache.log4j does not exist
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[24,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CustomAuthentificationProvider
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\AbstractController.ja
va:[49,20] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method getAllSkills()
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.services.UtilService
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[24,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable Logger
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CustomAuthentificationProvider
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[59,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[63,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[64,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[65,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\CustomAuthentificatio
nProvider.java:[66,17] [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type java.util.Hashtable
[ERROR] C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI\src\main\java\com\epam\hhsystem\web\controllers\VacancyMenuController
.java:[79,20] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method getAllSkills()
[ERROR] location: class com.epam.hhsystem.services.UtilService
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
C:\Users\Nikolay_Tkachev\workspace\HHSystem\UI>
```

Comment: can you try to do in your project directory mvn clean test? And also in your STS before doing the Maven Test can you try to cleanup your project? (Project -> Clean)

Comment: Read my update please

Comment: Can you post your poms? By this it looks like you have a multi module project and your UI does not know about the project containing the DatabaseHelper.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the maven lifecycle. By running maven test you are running the validate, compile and test phases of the build cycle maven.

You can check your maven dependency management to ensure that the class `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/epam/hhsystem/util/DatabaseHelper`
is in your maven managed dependencies of the project containing the test case.

**Build Cycle**

1. **validate** - validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available
2. **compile** - compile the source code of the project
3. **test** - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or deployed
4. **package** - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.
5. **integration-test** - process and deploy the package if necessary into an environment where integration tests can be run
6. **verify** - run any checks to verify the package is valid and meets quality criteria
7. **install** - install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally
8. **deploy** - done in an integration or release environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.

Maven Lifecycle: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: If I invoke maven install I see same result

Comment: Yes that is because you will run all the phases prior to install. By running install you will run (validate -> compile -> test -> package -> integration-test -> verify -> install)